# How actually magnetic flux change explains inducing of current.?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauss-law, electromagnetic-induction

If a bar magnet is moved towards a coil, current is induced as there is a flux change.
Consider a circular coil where magnetic field is there only inside the coil covering a concentric area of less than coil's area, implying that the magnetic field inside the coil has no interaction (contact) with coil. If that magnetic field is changed uniformly in magnitude there is induction of current as the flux associated with coil changes.

Intuitively,  the coil is not in the region with magnetic field (no interaction between magnetic field and coil)  then how flux explains induction of current?

Comment: Magnetic field actually fills all space.

Comment: Though field is there in space  magnetic field which is provided will affect the field only in the region where it has been provided,   right?

Comment: It means there is magnetic field where the wire of the coil is. You can't restrict it to be confined to a region in the interior of the coil.

Comment: Magnetic field is not due to coil as no current through it. It is due to external magnetic source.

Comment: I know. The bar magnet's field is nonzero at the wire.

Comment: @GRAVITON PI for that to happen the radius of the coil should be extremely large or to say infinite as compared to the magnetic field region i.e. we can't have such a coil and such a condition.